# CListCtrl do action based on selected row values

Tags: c++, mfc, legacy

I have to enable/disable buttons on a dialog based on values in a CListViewCtrl. Based on the selected row. I got this far:

```
NOTIFY_HANDLER(IDC_LIST, LVN_ITEMCHANGED, OnMyListChange)

// ....

    LRESULT OnMyListChange(int, LPNMHDR pNMHDR, BOOL&)
    {
        NM_LISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;
        if ((pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) 
            && (pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED))
        {
            // enable/disable buttons based on row field value
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Lets say I have `column1` `column2` `column3`. I need to write a condition based on `column2` value in the selected row. Multiple row selection is not a case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method [GetItemText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class#getitemtext). Notice it refers to:

> `nItem`
> The index of the item whose text is to be retrieved.
>
> `nSubItem`
> Specifies the subitem whose text is to be retrieved.

Think of them as *row* and *column*. Now, look at the [NM_LISTVIEW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774773(v=vs.85).aspx) structure in your handler:

```
typedef struct tagNMLISTVIEW {
  NMHDR  hdr;
  int    iItem;
  int    iSubItem;
  UINT   uNewState;
  UINT   uOldState;
  UINT   uChanged;
  POINT  ptAction;
  LPARAM lParam;
} NMLISTVIEW, *LPNMLISTVIEW;
```

It too has those properties:

```
int    iItem;
int    iSubItem;
```

So you should be able to get at the item text and perform what you wanted to do. Example:

```
// Get text in column 2 (it might 1 - can't remember if it is zero based indexing)
CString strValue = m_myList.GetItemText(pNMListView->iItem, 2);
if(strValue == "DoThis")
{
    // ...
}
```

The above code is **not** tested!!

Comment: Thank you. It turned out I got the whole thing wrong. We had the dialog data in lets say `m_dialogData` so I just requested the index of the selected row with `GetSelectedIndex()` and used it on `m_dialgData`.